# reverse order columns/diag in matrix julia

Tags: matrix, julia

This is my first 30 minutes with Julia.

The goal is to find out what the contents are of the two diagonals of a matrix (upperleft->lowerright and upperright->lowerleft). Julia is new to me so my approach is to reverse the original matrix' columns such that I can use the `diag` function on both.

The following code rearranges the columns.

```
state = [ 0 1 2; 1 2 0; 0 2 1]
result = zeros(3,3)
for col=[1:3]
    result[:, col] =  state[:,4-col]
end
```

I can confirm that the code does what I want it to do.

```
> println(state)
[0 1 2
 1 2 0
 0 2 1]
> println(result)
[2.0 1.0 0.0
 0.0 2.0 1.0
 1.0 2.0 0.0]
```

And I can find the two diagonals I want.

```
> println(diag(state))
[0,2,1]
> println(diag(result))
[2.0,2.0,0.0]
```

It feels like I could be doing this in a one-liner or through a native function that I didn't find in the documentation. Both the for loop at the column reverse and the use of two diag calls seems like I am repeating myself a little bit.

What is the best (pythonic but juliathonic) way of achieving what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One Julian way of doing this is to use comprehensions:

```
julia> M = randn(5,5)
5x5 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.0560902  -0.949341   -0.525774  -1.46393   -0.30404
 -0.409552    1.60397     1.18376   -0.397768   0.37188
  0.581681    0.18783    -0.611989  -1.03926   -0.240255
  0.0336476  -1.6296     -0.183579  -0.223435  -0.0134303
 -0.16528    -0.0928992   0.412221  -1.61453    0.564105

julia> [ M[i,i] for i=1:5 ]
5-element Array{Any,1}:
 -0.0560902
  1.60397
 -0.611989
 -0.223435
  0.564105

julia> [ M[i,5-i+1] for i=1:5 ]
5-element Array{Any,1}:
 -0.30404
 -0.397768
 -0.611989
 -1.6296
 -0.16528
```

In global scope, that produces Any arrays, which is less than optimal. You can fix that by declaring `M` to be constant: `const M = randn(5,5)`. Alternately, if the comprehensions appear in local scopes, they will be well typed.

Comment: list comprehension, nice. when I reverse the order of the columns with your method the output seems a little different though. ```A = [0 1 2; 2 2 2; 0 1 2]``` println ```[0 1 2 \n
 2 2 2 \n
 0 1 2]``` while ```M = [ A[:,4-i] for i=1:3 ]``` println  ```[[2,2,2],[1,2,1],[0,2,0]]```. Is there any real difference between these two types of has it just been printed differently?

Comment: Yes, you're taking slices so you get an array of arrays.